# Show tick mark (wingdings font)

Tags: jasper-reports

I am trying to show a tick mark (character code 0xFC) belonging to Wingdings font on a static text element in *Jaspersoft Studio*. But this tickmark doesn't appear when I do a preview of the report.

What I have done so far.

- Dragged a static text element onto the report
- Changed the font to wingdings and entered the text as 0xFC

On clicking preview I only see see 4 boxes & not the tick mark

Note: I do have this font on my computer.

Comment: You should post the *jrxml* file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution. Earlier I was trying to enter character code in the text box. Now I copied the font from the character Map to MS Word & from there I copied the font to my report. Now it seems to appear correctly